# how to Cast string to a given Enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

how to cast string enum ?

i have the code below , it gives me error when i try to assign string to levelEnum, where levelEnum is an Enumeration..

```
foreach (CustomProperty prop in requirementTemplate.AttributesCustomList)
{
    if (prop.Name == property)
    {
        return (CRF_DB.CRF_Requirement.LevelEnum) (prop.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to put select Enum item  by assigning value to it ?

hope it is clear enough

Comment: What's the type of the value returned by `prop.Value`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
return (CRF_DB.CRF_Requirement.LevelEnum)Enum.Parse(
  typeof(CRF_DB.CRF_Requirement.LevelEnum), 
  prop.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at Enum.TryParse

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid an exception you can check if the value exists within that enumeration by calling `IsDefined`. The `TryParse` method would be the optimal solution if you're using .NET 4.0.

```
foreach (CustomProperty prop in requirementTemplate.AttributesCustomList)
{
    if (prop.Name == property && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LevelEnum), prop.Value))
    {
        return (LevelEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(LevelEnum), prop.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```